# How to add Images, Text or Video into a Video

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing

I have static images, text and some video footage.

How can I add these into a Video Template?

Is there some codec to do this through command line? As I want to implement this online on a server? Something similar to www.animoto.com

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Particularly about animoto I think (no-no-no, I'm pretty sure about it!) that it uses predesigned projects in post-production video software like Adobe After Effects and then use its API to paste user's footage into it and adjust project accordingly.

What about AE, it renders rich API to the developer (Javascript). It's pretty simple and a good programmer with even a little JS experience can implement automation of image-insertion in short time!

Related reading: http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get the frames, do something to them and then recompile.

I don't know about a Video Template, but I do know a site where you can get loads of info about creating such layers on images and videos:

[The Broadcaster Project](http://broadcasterproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/how-to-layerremix-videos-with-free-command-line-tools/)

There was also a question about this on [super user](https://superuser.com/questions/107260/is-there-a-server-side-video-manipulation-software)

I recommend you use something like [AVISynth](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page) but I don't know how easy it is to implement in online environments.

Maybe you should just go for a more webbased solution such as adobe flash, just as [this](http://demo.mixmoov-studio.com/flex/demo.html) following company did.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is lot software witch can help you . I have use coral `vedioStudio` and `adobe video editer` and online free services [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/editor)